# log4net StringMatchFilter with RegexToMatch not working

Tags: c#, log4net

I am having trouble getting log4net StringMatchFilter to match anything when using RegexToMatch property.

I have some methods:

```
    static public IFilter GetStringMatchFilter(string stringToMatch)
    {
        StringMatchFilter filter = new StringMatchFilter();
        filter.StringToMatch = stringToMatch;
        return filter;
    }

    static public IFilter GetRegexMatchFilter(string regexToMatch)
    {
        StringMatchFilter filter = new StringMatchFilter();
        filter.RegexToMatch = regexToMatch;
        return filter;
    }
    static public IFilter GetDenyAllFilter()
    {
        DenyAllFilter filter = new DenyAllFilter();
        return filter;
    }
```

This StringToMatch code works:

```
        appender.AddFilter(GetStringMatchFilter("SomeString"));
        appender.AddFilter(GetDenyAllFilter());
        appender.ActivateOptions();
```

But this code matches nothing:

```
        appender.AddFilter(GetRegexMatchFilter(@".*"));
        appender.AddFilter(GetDenyAllFilter());
        appender.ActivateOptions();
```

Am I formatting my regex string wrong? I have tried many permutations but nothing seems to match for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a small bug to me because I had the same problem understanding why the filter wasn't working for me until I looked at the source code and realized that you have to explicitly call **ActivateOptions** (which translates the regular expression string to a Regex class) on the filter when using **RegexToMatch** property, otherwise it returns FilterDecision.Neutral.

Working code:

```
static public IFilter GetRegexMatchFilter(string regexToMatch)
{
    StringMatchFilter filter = new StringMatchFilter();
    filter.RegexToMatch = regexToMatch;
    filter.ActivateOptions(); //this line must be added
    return filter;
}
```

Comment: Hi, finally was able to get back to it and test it. It is working now, thanks!